# Ignore certain columns on update

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-database-first

Hello I have something like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var movie = (from m in _db.Movies where m.Id == id select m).First();

    return View(movie);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Movie movie)
{
    try
    {
        var originalMovie = (from m in _db.Movies where m.Id == movie.Id select m).First();

        _db.Movies.ApplyCurrentValues(movie);

        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

This example was taken from [Proper way to Edit an entity in MVC 3 with the Entity Framework using Data Model First approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827214/proper-way-to-edit-an-entity-in-mvc-3-with-the-entity-framework-using-data-model)

I want to pass to the DB SQL-query (UPDATE Movie ....) only modified columns because I'm doing a column audit.

The code works ok, but the problem is that in my "Movie" Entity I have a "FlagOldMovie" property and others 10 properties witch I'm not using its in this view because they will stay the same, but the entityframework put to that properties defaults values so the "ApplyCurrentValues" find changes and that properties are updated too.

A workaround is to pass my not changed properties to html hidden inputs, but its privated data.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it, first at all, the solution only works on .NET 4.5+

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Movie movie)
{
    try
    {
        //Get DB version
        var originalMovie = (from m in _db.Movies where m.Id == movie.Id select m).First();
        //Mark changes with data received
        _db.Movies.ApplyCurrentValues(movie);

        //CODE ADDED - Ignoring field/properties you dont want to update to DB
        ObjectStateEntry entryToUpdate = db.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(originalMovil);
        entryToUpdate.RejectPropertyChanges("field1");
        entryToUpdate.RejectPropertyChanges("field2");
        entryToUpdate.RejectPropertyChanges("field3");
        //-----------------

        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

With this code, the only data modified is witch you want, next what I did is to audit columns changed extending _db.SaveChanges() to _db.SaveChangesAudito(id);

Answer (score 3):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Exclude ="column_name")] Movie movie)
{
//code here
}
```

This would ignore the column you specify, I usually do that to exclude fields like `Id`.

But if you are ignoring to many columns then you should consider ViewModel concept where you just have only properties you need for a view.

EDIT: Still some issues?

Here is how you add multiple ones

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Exclude ="c_name, c_name2, c_name3")] Movie movie)
{
//code here
}
```

Comment: This seems the solution I was looking for, but I don't know why is not working for me... thank you... I'll try to find te problem.

Comment: What is the problem? maybe I can help you further

Comment: It isn't excluding the columns, I don't know if it is because the columns i want to exclude are not-nulleables or because my action is little more complex than the example, something like: public ActionResult Edit(Movie movie, string a, int b, int c)

Comment: I updated my question, try showing some of your model and view, it will help also

Comment: Thank you for the edit, but fails with one exclude too. I can find an example with Edits, all examples in internet are with Create (using it with AddObject instead ApplyCurrentValues), I also tried: ModelState.Remove("column_nma") I simplified my code to be same as example, doesnt work too.. :/

Comment: Ok but why cant you just create a model with just what you need, or just remove them from your view completly, even if you don't like that just try it to see if that solves it

Comment: Bind is not for this purpose. Bind prevents an over posting attack whereby a client can overpost fieldnames and values i.e. "IsAdmin=true" and due to the default model binding behaviour if the model has an IsAdmin field it will be set to true even if you omitted it from the client output i..e no field in the html to set IsAdmin.  Bind does nothing at the data tier which is the Ops question. All it does it omit a bind in the client value to the entity, so you will still get defaults values etc being sent to the data tier and thus being entered into the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell EF which fields you want to update. Try something like this:

```
_db.Movies.Attach(movie);
ObjectStateEntry entryToUpdate = db.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(movie);
entryToUpdate.SetModifiedProperty("field1"); // Replace "field1" with the name of the 1st field to update
entryToUpdate.SetModifiedProperty("field2"); // Replace "field2" with the name of the 2nd field to update
entryToUpdate.SetModifiedProperty("field3"); // Replace "field3" with the name of the 3rd field to update
_db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try, it is possible to do the inverse, to set all properties modifieds (like my code does) and with this coode unset those I'm not using it?

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to use a ViewModel and not a domain/data model to pass to/from your views. :)

This scenario illustrates one of the dangers of not doing so.

Answer (score 0):

try like that

```
var originalMovie = (from m in _db.Movies where m.Id == movie.Id select m).First();

originalMovie.updateme = updating;

_db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your answer, what is "updating"?

Comment: ahh! by the way, thank you for your reply, but I was looking for a flag or something in configuration to tell EF ignore thats columns without retyping all the code and keeping the code short and clear, I have to do it for all my CRUD operations in the app, this for example exposes to the view 20 properties. But its an accepted approach.